# How do you set the Windows SDK target version in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I recently installed the Windows 8 SDK version (8.0 & 8.0A) along with the VS2011 Beta.  This has had the effect of making all my VS2010 projects attempt to build against Windows SDK version 8.0 instead of 7.1A (which they're supposed to build against).  I'm trying to figure out how to set which SDK should be used as the target version.  I've found this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764.aspx

Which states:

To use the Windows SDK tools in Visual Studio 2010

- In Visual Studio 2010, open a solution (.sln) file or create a solution.
- In Solution Explorer, right-click the solution node and then click Properties.
- In the Configuration list, select All Configurations.
- Under Configuration Properties, select General.
- As the Platform Toolset option, select Windows7.1SDK.
- Click OK.

However there is no "General" option under configuration properties....  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you found is slightly wrong: it's available in the *project* properties, not the solution properties:

[image: Platform Toolset]

Comment: +1 Yes I found this too, sadly that means changing all 300 projects in my solution :-(

Comment: It should be relatively easy to manually modify one project, see how it's saved in the project file, and then programmatically apply that same change from a script or program to all projects, though.

Comment: you can select multiple projects at once.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 So you can, can't believe I didn't realise this before.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟, I was afraid of that.  I am working in a solution with 10s of projects in folders...

Answer (score 0):

Building against the 8.0 SDK should not be a problem if you [appropriately define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` before including `windows.h`. Did you try this?

Comment: I can't build against the 8.0 SDK yet for contractual reasons, the whole team is building against 7.1.  We do already set WINVER etc but I definately need to build against the 7.1 SDK for now.

Comment: @Benj Could you avoid that problem by developing against the 8.0 SDK, and building on a separate build server against the 7.1 SDK?

Comment: @hvd - Yes, in fact we do have just such a build server.  However it is kind of nice to be able to build locally (I get shouted at if I break the build on the server).  There used to be an SDK Configuration Tool that let you set the intended target but it's not supported > VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

I usually define solution wide the following predefined macros for Windows XP SP3:

```
WINVER=0x0501
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501
NTDDI_VERSION=0x05010300
```

Similarly you could define your own Windows version: [more info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)